# applications of finding least quadratic nonresidue mod $p$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

I saw some papers from famous mathematicians (assuming GRH or without it) which are devoted to finding bound for least quadratic nonresidues modulo prime number $p$.

My question is that why it is so important and what are the applications of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a recent paper? What estimate have they proved? Anyway, this is a classical, notoriously difficult problem; so, definitely interesting on its own.

Comment: @Seva, no. they are classic. but I saw one related to from Terence Tao (The Elliott–Halberstam conjecture implies the Vinogradov least quadratic nonresidue conjecture).

Comment: For instance, if we want to explicitly construct a field with $p^2$ elements,  we can take the quotient $$\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-a),$$
where $a$ is *not* a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Tonelli–Shanks algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Let me expand my comment into a short answer.

The explicit knowledge of a quadratic nonresidue $a$ modulo $p$ allows us to construct the irreducible quadratic polynomial $x^2-a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, and so we have a very explicit description of the field with $p^2$ elements as $$\mathbb{F}_{p^2}=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-a).$$